# JMeter fails running test

Tags: jmeter

I'm running some performance test on JMeter from a Java program on IntelliJ. Some test run well but sometimes I get this error:

```
An error occurred: null
errorlevel=1
```

This is what I'm getting on the log file

```
2022-03-11 16:55:35,944 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.createStatistic(JsonExporter.java:121) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.JsonExporter.export(JsonExporter.java:72) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.exportData(ReportGenerator.java:379) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.generate(ReportGenerator.java:257) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.3]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_291]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:254) [ApacheJMeter.jar:5.4.3]
```

And this is what I get when I debbug the report generation

```
###### [INFO] Will generate HTML report in C:\Users\Exiuser\Documents\qa_can_webservices\jmeter-PerfTest\target\jmeter\reports\Template_PortalPOSTToken
###### [INFO] Executing test: Template_PortalPOSTToken.jmx
###### [INFO] Arguments for forked JMeter JVM: [java, -Xms512M, -Xmx512M, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -jar, ApacheJMeter-5.4.1.jar, -d, C:\Users\Exiuser\Documents\qa_can_webservices\jmeter-PerfTest\target\a07895b0-cee6-4ccb-944c-589f09d421bc\jmeter, -e, -j, C:\Users\Exiuser\Documents\qa_can_webservices\jmeter-PerfTest\target\jmeter\logs\Template_PortalPOSTToken.jmx.log, -l, C:\Users\Exiuser\Documents\qa_can_webservices\Clientes\src\test\resources\CSVDatasTets\Clientes\ClaimChannelAPI\POST_Claim\LoadTest-1Users\20220314-Template_PortalPOSTToken.csv, -n, -o, C:\Users\Exiuser\Documents\qa_can_webservices\jmeter-PerfTest\target\jmeter\reports\Template_PortalPOSTToken, -t, C:\Users\Exiuser\Documents\qa_can_webservices\jmeter-PerfTest\target\jmeter\testFiles\Template_PortalPOSTToken.jmx, -Dsun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders, true]
###### [INFO]  
###### [INFO] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
###### [INFO] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Exiuser/Documents/qa_can_webservices/jmeter-PerfTest/target/a07895b0-cee6-4ccb-944c-589f09d421bc/jmeter/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.13.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
###### [INFO] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Exiuser/Documents/qa_can_webservices/jmeter-PerfTest/target/a07895b0-cee6-4ccb-944c-589f09d421bc/jmeter/lib/slf4j-nop-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
###### [INFO] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
###### [INFO] SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
###### [INFO] Creating summariser <summary>
###### [INFO] Created the tree successfully using C:\Users\Exiuser\Documents\qa_can_webservices\jmeter-PerfTest\target\jmeter\testFiles\Template_PortalPOSTToken.jmx
###### [INFO] Starting standalone test @ Mon Mar 14 09:08:12 ART 2022 (1647259692040)
###### [INFO] Waiting for possible Shutdown/StopTestNow/HeapDump/ThreadDump message on port 4445
###### [INFO] summary =      0 in 00:00:00 = **/s Avg:     0 Min: 9223372036854775807 Max: -9223372036854775808 Err:     0 (0,00%)
###### [INFO] Tidying up ...    @ Mon Mar 14 09:08:13 ART 2022 (1647259693523)
###### [INFO] Error generating the report: java.lang.NullPointerException
###### [INFO] ... end of run
```

Comment: See jmeter.log for errors

Comment: I've edited the post with the log info

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean that JMeter "fails running test", it means that JMeter fails to generate [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

1. Check your [.jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/jmeter/JtlFiles), it might be incomplete or corrupt
2. [Enable JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) for the reporting component by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.report" level="debug" />
   ```

   and look for the following entry in the [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging):

   ```
   Creating statistics for result data:
   ```

   inspect the object in that line, it will give you a clue regarding what could go wrong

Comment: I added to the post what I got activating the logging debug. I can't find the .jtl file. And there is no line that says that in the log file, the only thing similar is "Creating statistics for overall" and right after that is the log that was on the post

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I was reading a csv file and generate html reports from the file. The csv was empty and the reason was that the server had no memory allocated for the tests.